# Ant error: <buildfile> is not an absolute path

Tags: ant

I'm trying to use Ant 1.7 but running into a problem.  In my current directory, I have a build file called warupdate.xml.  From within this directory, I execute:

/opt/apache-ant-1.7.0/bin/ant -f warupdate.xml

I then get the following error:

Buildfile: warupdate.xml

BUILD FAILED
./warupdate.xml is not an absolute path

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Matt

Comment: What does `warupdate.xml` look like? What if you rename it to `build.xml`? Why give the long path to `ant`? Is it not in your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Why name it anything other than `build.xml`?  It's the standard, ant will expect it and then you can simply just run ant from that directory without specifying a build file.

Comment: This is part of a 3rd party install...so we can view the scripts, but prefer not to customize them. We are working with the vendor too, but seemed like something I might be able to solve as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my `warupdate.xml`:

```
<project>
    <echo>Tada!</echo>
</project>
```

Here's my Ant command:

```
$ /opt/ant/bin/ant -f warupdate.xml
Buildfile: /Users/david/warupdate.xml
     [echo] Tada!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Basically, it works.

Something else is going on, and you're not giving the *full story*. What does `warupdate.xml` look like? What if you use `ant -d` to get a verbose debugging output. Maybe that will show you what's going on. Why are you giving the full path to `ant`?

You have to give us more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to give a bigger picture. The command is part of a script. The script first does a cd to the path that contains warupdate.xml (which is different then the location of the ant binary). That's why it is giving the full path to ant. I guess what it will really come down to, is where will ant look for build files if only a relative path is given?  This is part of a 3rd party install...so we can view the scripts, but prefer not to customize them.  We are working with the vendor too, but seemed like something I might be able to solve as well.

Comment: Bash Shell Script? Add `set -xv` to the top of the script. This turns on debugging and verbose modes, and will let you see exactly what your script is doing and executing. That might help pin down the issue